# Openning an RTSP port in linux

Tags: networking, port, rtsp

I want to check if a client can access a server via rtsp://192.168.1.5:554. As you can see the rtsp protocol and port #554 must be open and working on the server.

Can I add

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 554 -j ACCEPT
```

but the protocol is specified as tcp. changing that to `-p rtsp` doesn't work either.

Any idea on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RTSP is just another application layer protocol layered on top of TCP or UDP, like HTTP or FTP.  As [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol) puts it

> The default transport layer port number is 554 for both TCP and UDP, the latter being rarely used for the control requests.

If you open up TCP and UDP, you should be fine.